# fopen using append on EXISTING files (malfunction)

Tags: c, append, fopen

Hi all I am relatively new to programming.  Currently my code is working "correctly"

What I want to do is open a file for appending and then use couple different other source files to put data on the target file for appending.

The problem is that whenever I use fopen on the file name, it does not open the existing file but rather creates a file with no extension (all the files are in the same directory so should be able to open no problem).  This is the code I am using to grab the necessary information for which file to append (error is never generated because it just creates a new file)

```
FILE *fp_target;

char target[100];

fgets(target, 99, stdin);

if ((fp_target = fopen(target, "a"))==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "the following target file %s can not be appended", target);
    exit (0);
}
```

Actually I tried this test a couple times and when i do this again with the same name used in the first try (lets say I used test.c) the program will open the test.c(no extension rather than the file "test extension (.c)")

can anyone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

also, when I fopen a file for reading it will read the file with the extension

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of "target"? Perhaps the problem is that your input is being truncated (due to the 99 char limit)? I suggest using "getdelim" or "getline" instead of "fgets", since it is a much safer function to use for this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the newline from the input. By using

```
target[strlen(target)-1]='\0';
```

`strlen()` is used to find the length of the string which is available in `string.h` header file.

`strlen(target)-1` which is used to find the newline location `\0` the null character is pasted so the new line is removed.

If you worked with that new line the file is created as `test.c?`.

In disk we cannot create a file with the already exist name. So the newline is act as one character and the file name is created as like a existing name.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually was working on this problem for a good half hour on this issue before posting.  But right after posting I came to the same conclusion!  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `fgets(target, 99, stdin);` line. After giving input 'test.c' it takes some garbage values till the end of the array. so every time it creates a new file. Instaed of `fgets` use `scanf` to get the input from user.

```
scanf("%s",target);
if ((fp_target = fopen(target, "a"))==NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "the following target file %s can not be appended", target);
   exit (0);
}
```

If you want to use `fgets` to read the input from the user, after the user input make it `NULL`.

```
fgets(target, 99, stdin);
target[strlen(target)-1]='\0';
```